# Multiple sub-queries ... Better way to

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

First of all sorry if my English Level isn't so high :-)

I need some help with a SQL Server Query ... (I'm a little new in SQL).

I have a table with products stock in a specific date (a day) of some products. Not everyday has a stock record if there aren't stock movement. This is my table:

```
Table : Stocks

Columns : ProductCode | Date | Stock |
```

Every time we make a stock movement we add a new row, so it's possible found some days w/out records in a lot of Product Codes

If I need a product stock in a specific day this is my SQL Query

```
Date : 1-4-2016
Product : bm500w
```

```
 select top 1 stock 
 from stocks 
 where productcode = 'bm500w' 
 and Date <= '1-4-2016' 
 order by Date desc
```

This query is working, but I have a new "Chief Request". I need a query to view Stock of a specific product in the last 30 days.

The query should be:

---

```
select top 1 ProductCode,
       (select top 1 Stock from Stocks  where ProductCode = mv.ProductCode 
        and Date <= getdate()-1 order by Date desc) as Dia1,
       (select top 1 Stock from Stocks  where ProductCode = mv.ProductCode 
        and Date <= getdate()-2 order by Date desc) as Dia2,
       (select top 1 Stock from Stocks  where ProductCode = mv.ProductCode 
        and Date <= getdate()-29 order by Date desc) as Dia29,
       (select top 1 Stock from Stocks  where ProductCode = mv.ProductCode 
        and Date <= getdate()-30 order by Date desc) as Dia30
from Stocks mv 
where mv.ProductCode = 'bm500w'
```

---

I'm sure this query works but I'm sure, sure, sure there is a better , "optimized",  method or code to obtain the same results.

Comment: what is the data-type of Date? string or dateformat?

Comment: is it absolutely necessary that the stocks are in one line?
having a list of dates and stock would be a lot easier

Comment: Do you use `Date <= '1-4-2016` because if there's no record for that day you need to get the most recent record before it?

Comment: The data-type of Date is dateformat.

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely necessary that the stocks are in one line, because there are more than one productcode .... I need a line for every productcode ... :-(

Comment: Josh, yes this is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use union, however you can use join using the same method.

```
declare @sqlStr nvarchar(max) = ';with cte as (' + char(13)

declare @i int = 1

while @i <= 30
begin
    set @sqlStr = @sqlStr + 
        'select top 1 Stock as Dia from Stocks  where ProductCode = mv.ProductCode and Date <= getdate() - ' + cast(@i as varchar) + ' order by Date desc' + CHAR(13)

    if (@i < 30)
        set @sqlStr = @sqlStr + 'union all' + CHAR(13)

    set @i = @i + 1
end
set @sqlStr = @sqlStr + ')' + CHAR(13) + 'select top 1 ProductCode, cte.Dia from Stocks mv inner join cte on cte.ProductCode = mv.ProductCode where mv.ProductCode = @prdCode' 
print @sqlStr
exec sp_executesql @sqlStr, N'bm500w'
```

**Note:**
*when I use @i inside the first statement, I think there might be risk of SQL injection, so be aware of that if you are concern about security.*

*Please "Mark as Answer" if a post has answered the question*

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I need some more standard .... I have to use the query in a Excel Import ... I think this is perfect for a direct query, but I think this is going to fail if I use in Excel data import .... :-(